# Tuning a group by thats running slowly

Tags: sql, sql-server

The following SQL takes 5 seconds on a database with the largest table PremiseProviderBillings having 350,000 records. But on same database with 1.5 million records it takes over a minute

```
SELECT
   n.CustomerInvoiceNumberId as InvoiceNo,C.CustomerBillId,c.customerid, S.Volumetric, S.Fixed, S.VAT, S.Discount, C.Debit,c.EffectiveDate,c.TransactionDateTime,s.Consumption,r.CustomerCreditNoteId--,s.Volumetric + s.Fixed + s.Vat - s.discount - c.debit as variance
FROM
  CustomerPayments C 
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT
     CustomerBillId, SUM(a.VolumetricCharge) as Volumetric,SUM(a.FixedCharge) as Fixed,
     SUM(a.VAT) as VAT,SUM(a.Discount) as Discount,sum(a.EstimatedConsumption) as Consumption
   FROM
     PremiseProviderBillings a, PremiseProviderBills b
    WHERE a.PremiseProviderBillId = b.PremiseProviderBillId
   GROUP BY
     CustomerBillId) S
ON
  C.CustomerBillId = S.CustomerBillId 
  and debit <> 0 -- hide credit note lines, we mark these results with customerCreditNoteId to show they have been credited
INNER JOIN dbo.CustomerInvoiceNumbers n on c.CustomerBillId = n.CustomerBillId
left OUTER JOIN
           dbo.CustomerCreditNotes AS r ON c.CustomerPaymentId = r.CustomerPaymentId
where isnull(c.transactionDateTimeEnd,'')=''
```

if I then run the inner SQL part that sums the values on the smaller database it takes 2 seconds. On the bigger database it takes 34 seconds, inner SQL below...

```
SELECT
     CustomerBillId, SUM(a.VolumetricCharge) as Volumetric,SUM(a.FixedCharge) as Fixed,
     SUM(a.VAT) as VAT,SUM(a.Discount) as Discount,sum(a.EstimatedConsumption) as Consumption
   FROM
     PremiseProviderBillings a, PremiseProviderBills b
    WHERE a.PremiseProviderBillId = b.PremiseProviderBillId
   GROUP BY
     CustomerBillId
```

So its clear that this SQL is simply not scale-able. Given that the database will grow what technique should one apply to improve this?

I have checked all joins to ensure that there are no missing indexes, well, to ensure that all joins are key based and ok

I would have thought this approach is ok but should I alter the structure of the SQL, is this non scale-able and inefficient?

Regards

Comment: What are the indexes in PremiseProviderBillings and PremiseProviderBills? Query plan + statistics IO output could help solving this too.

Comment: When your group by some value,SQL  tries to do a distinct to eliminate duplicates...so the Group by column should be indexed or atleast you should give hint to SQL stating this column is unique.Next would be the sum columns.. are they included in index as covering

Comment: "the largest table PremiseProviderBillings having 350,000 records. But on the same database with 1.5 million records it takes over a minute", well here you are not getting data only from this table. So it will be more accurate to measure scalability based on row count of the joined output:  "PremiseProviderBillings a, PremiseProviderBills b
    WHERE a.PremiseProviderBillId = b.PremiseProviderBillId". Are the amounts of rows of the joined output still: 350K and 1.5M?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the query often enough, and depending on how often you write to the tables it might be worth creating an [indexed view](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms191432.aspx) for this. It is however worth noting that this is speculation, and indexed views do come with a trade off, your reads will be faster but your writes will be slower.

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.CustomerBillingView
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
    SELECT  b.CustomerBillId,
            SUM(a.VolumetricCharge) AS Volumetric,
            SUM(a.FixedCharge) AS Fixed,
            SUM(a.VAT) AS VAT,
            SUM(a.Discount) AS Discount,
            SUM(a.EstimatedConsumption) AS Consumption,
            COUNT_BIG(*) AS Records -- REQUIRED TO CREATE INDEX
    FROM    dbo.PremiseProviderBillings a
            INNER JOIN dbo.PremiseProviderBills b
                ON a.PremiseProviderBillId = b.PremiseProviderBillId
    GROUP BY b.CustomerBillId;
GO

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX UQ_CustomerBillingView__CustomerBillId
    ON dbo.CustomerBillingView (CustomerBillId);

GO
```

Then you just need to use your view with the hint `NOEXPAND` to ensure that the index is used.

```
SELECT  n.CustomerInvoiceNumberId as InvoiceNo,
        c.CustomerBillId,
        c.customerid, 
        s.Volumetric, 
        s.Fixed, 
        s.VAT, 
        s.Discount, 
        c.Debit,
        c.EffectiveDate,
        c.TransactionDateTime,
        s.Consumption,
        r.CustomerCreditNoteId
        --,s.Volumetric + s.Fixed + s.Vat - s.discount - c.debit as variance
FROM    CustomerPayments AS c 
        INNER JOIN dbo.CustomerBillingView AS s WITH (NOEXPAND)
            ON c.CustomerBillId = s.CustomerBillId 
            AND c.Debit <> 0 
            -- hide credit note lines, we mark these results with customerCreditNoteId to show they have been credited
        INNER JOIN dbo.CustomerInvoiceNumbers n 
            ON c.CustomerBillId = n.CustomerBillId
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.CustomerCreditNotes AS r 
            ON c.CustomerPaymentId = r.CustomerPaymentId
WHERE   ISNULL(c.transactionDateTimeEnd,'') = '';
```

As with every query tuning question, you are the only one with all the information needed to answer properly. 
In my experience (which is primarily in billing systems), indexed views like this are generally okay with billing data, because most invoice runs are cyclical,
and so writes are in batches rather than continual, and reads also tend to outweigh writes because the data is static, once an invoice is created then it 
is very rarely updated.

Comment: it says Cannot schema bind view 'dbo.CustomerBillingView' because name 'PremiseProviderBillings' is invalid for schema binding. Names must be in two-part format and an object cannot reference itself

when i try to create, any ideas, looks promising your solution, thanks

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the schema prefix to the tables used in the view. In order to create the index the view must be schemabound, and in order to be schema bound the schema prefix has to be used everywhere (although it is a [good idea to use it everywhere anyway](https://sqlblog.org/2019/09/12/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix)

Comment: Quite amazing, thank you very much GarethD. 1 second execution each time

Answer (score 0):

Try using a common table expression for your inner query, it might speed things a little.

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT
         CustomerBillId, SUM(a.VolumetricCharge) as Volumetric,SUM(a.FixedCharge) as Fixed,
         SUM(a.VAT) as VAT,SUM(a.Discount) as Discount,sum(a.EstimatedConsumption) as Consumption
       FROM
         PremiseProviderBillings a, PremiseProviderBills b
        WHERE a.PremiseProviderBillId = b.PremiseProviderBillId
       GROUP BY
         CustomerBillId
)   

SELECT
   n.CustomerInvoiceNumberId as InvoiceNo,C.CustomerBillId,c.customerid, S.Volumetric, S.Fixed, S.VAT, S.Discount, C.Debit,c.EffectiveDate,c.TransactionDateTime,s.Consumption,r.CustomerCreditNoteId--,s.Volumetric + s.Fixed + s.Vat - s.discount - c.debit as variance
FROM
  CustomerPayments C 
INNER JOIN
  CTE S
ON
  C.CustomerBillId = S.CustomerBillId 
  and debit <> 0 -- hide credit note lines, we mark these results with customerCreditNoteId to show they have been credited
INNER JOIN dbo.CustomerInvoiceNumbers n on c.CustomerBillId = n.CustomerBillId
left OUTER JOIN
           dbo.CustomerCreditNotes AS r ON c.CustomerPaymentId = r.CustomerPaymentId
where isnull(c.transactionDateTimeEnd,'')=''
```

Comment: This wouldn't make a difference at all. Whether the derived table is a subquery or a common table expression, the execution plan would be identical.

Comment: Would you use a temporary table instead @GarethD?

Comment: I wouldn't. There are times when materializing the subquery can help, but given the subquery on its own takes 34 seconds, this is unlikely to yield much of an increase in speed. I think the answer lies in indexing, but for optimisation questions it is largely guess work, since there are so many things to consider, most of which only the OP knows.

Comment: Wow this made a HUGE difference, 1 second to return results on the LARGE database, thanks!!!!! :-)

Comment: I spoke too soon, it runs fast sometimes on large dataset, other times it takes 1 minute and just keeps going. Very odd